# Background scroll issue with iframe on iOS iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, ipad

We're experiencing an issue with an iframe lightbox that occurs mostly on iPad's. The issue is sporadic, sometimes we can get it to scroll, other times it cannot scroll at all.

Here is a live example: http://story-teller-doreen-61750.bitballoon.com/

View this on an iPad, iPad Air, or iPad Pro using safari.

You'll notice that on the iPad, the background with the content scrolls, but the iframe does not scroll. However, sometimes when you change the orientation from portrait to landscape then back, the scrolling then works.

Is there a known solution to this issue? We've already attempted to try all the workarounds posted in various threads on stackoverflow and github with others experiencing this issue using bootstrap modals, but have not had any luck.

Comment: I have the same issue, both with light box/overlays, and iframes.  Very curious as to what makes it sometimes work, then not.  Might be input/cursor focus?